# Python replace where all characters are the same

Tags: python, replace

So, I'm creating a hangman-like game and am trying to replace a string like `"_ _ _ _ _ _"` with the character guessed in the right position. Let's say the word is `"pepsi"`, and I want to replace all the spots in `"_ _ _ _ _"` where there would be a `p`, as in the 1st and 3rd `_`. However, when doing `"_ _ _ _ _ ".replace("_", letter)`, this obviously replaces all of my underscores to "p", resulting in `"p p p p p"`.

Snippet of my code:

```py
while not guessed:
    word = random.choice(self.words)
    template = "_ "*len(word)
    letter = input("Guess a letter\n")
    if letter not in word: print("Incorrect")
    else:
        for x in range(len(word)):
            if word[x] == letter: 
                template.replace(template[x], letter)
    if "_" not in template: guessed = True
print(f"Guessed {word} in {10-lives} guesses!")
```

---

How should I replace a **specific** underscore from a string where every character is an underscore followed by a space?

Comment: Share your existing code please.

Comment: @Selcuk check my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can iterate each character in a word. Then check if the character in your **guessed words** or not. For example,

**Ex 1.** Using a simple loop

```
word = 'pepsi'
guessed = ['p', 'i']

for s in word:
    if s in guessed:
        print(s, end='')
    else:
        print(' _ ', end='')
```

Result:

```
p _ p _  i
```

**Ex 2.** Using list comprehension

```
res = [s if s in guessed else '_' for s in word]

# ['p', '_', 'p', '_', 'i']
```

Comment: Is there a way for my current code to be altered to work? These two approaches are drastically different from what I currently have

Comment: Also, this doesn't work when I guess the letter `e`, the `p` will be replaced with `_`, resulting in `"_ e _ _ _"`

Comment: @xupaii It works fine if you keep guessed words in a form of a list: guessed = ['p', 'e']

Comment: Oh, that's genius!! Thanks haha

Comment: @xupaii I hope my answer is helpful. Anyway, this is merely an idea. Don't forget to consider capital and small letters from user inputs, as well as the repetition of guessed words.